# Beamer presentation: edit information in bar at bottom of each slide

Tags: beamer

I use a Beamer presentation in Latex.

At the bottom of every slide a bar is automatically generated with author name, institute, presentation title, date and frame number

I do not want to display the information about the institute (only on title slide). Is this feasible?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\title{Title}
\date{Date}
\author{Name}
\institute{Institute}

\usetheme{quito-light}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[space]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the link to the theme I use:
https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/beamer-theme-template-quito-light/pyqxchbsknvr

Comment: If you use a non-standard theme, you should always include at least a link to the theme in your questions!

Comment: Oh, right, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of `\institute` to provide an alternative text for the footline -- this text can be empty:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\title{Title}
\date{Date}
\author{Name}
\institute[]{Institute}

\usetheme{quito-light}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[space]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That easy! Thank you